# How to exclude a class name in selenium (python)?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a data from a bookmaker website, but I need only non-live events. Non-live event block elements look like this: `<div class="card ng-star-inserted"`. But live event elements look like this: `<div class="card card--live ng-star-inserted`.
The code I used to get the names of competing teams:

```
website = 'https://winline.ru/stavki/sport/futbol'
driver.get(website)

team1 = []
team2 = []

driver.implicitly_wait(3)
table_winline_1 = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "card.ng-star-inserted")

for match in table_winline_1:
    team1.append(match.find_element(By.XPATH, './div[1]/a/div/div[1]').text)
    team2.append(match.find_element(By.XPATH, './div[1]/a/div/div[2]').text)
print(team1)
print(team2)
```

It gives me the list of teams, starting with teams from live events.
How can I exclude `div class="card card--live ng-star-inserted`?

I also tried using xpath and css selector locators but they return empty lists for some reason
English is not my first language, so I'm sorry if I made any mistakes in my message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think not contains in XPath can help you.

```
table_winline_1 = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "card ng-star-inserted") and not(contains(@class,"card--live))]')
```

The above statement will list all elements on the page that do not contain "card--live".
In driver.find_elements on line 8 you search for those with "card.ng-star-inserted" class, with this code you will get div elements that have the "card ng-star-inserted" class but not the "card--live" class on the entire page.

Comment: I don't quite understand where I should put that line for it to work. Should I put in my loop?

Comment: In driver.find_elements on line 8 you search for those with card.ng-star-inserted class, this is '//div[contains(@class, "card ng-star-inserted") and not(contains(@class,"card By using --live))]' you will get div elements that have the "card ng-star-inserted" class but not the "card--live" class on the entire page.

Comment: Please update your answer to include the information in your comment. This will avoid the ambiguity found by the OP and help future users to better understand your answer. Thanks

Comment: Don't know why, but this just returns two empty lists [ ] without any errors. Actually, I tried 'table_winline_1 = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class,"card ng-star-inserted")]')' and 'table_winline_1 = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class,"card--live")]')' and it's the same empty lists.

Comment: Did you try the xpath in chrome devtools? If you try it, we'll see if it works right.

Comment: Yeah, I did. Works there just fine

Comment: Actually, just tried again and found out that if I search //div[contains(@class,"card ng-star-inserted")] in devtools upon just reloading the page it can't find any elements, but if I scroll down then it does. Guess all elements don't load from the start so I'll have to add code that scrolls the page down or smth

Comment: Yes, such a situation may occur.  It may be rendered with javascript